# How do I correctly translate the activation email in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, translation

How do I translate the activation email after registration (build Auth in Laravel)?

I've made this translation in pl/pl.json:

> "If you’re having trouble clicking the": "Jeśli masz problem z
>   kliknięciem",
>       "button, copy and paste the URL below": " to skopiuj i wklej poniższy adres URL ",
>       "into your web browser": "  do przeglądarki internetowej"

but in mail I have this:

If you’re having trouble clicking the "Zweryfikuj adres email" button, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser: http://domain.test/email/verify/8?expires=1558113166&signature=2deea0aa937119efbf99ebbfc73bbf985f373491b47b0dcdfc76ee3b6dad6aeb

This is a mix of Polish and English. So I believe my translation is not working.

Comment: code please. Need to see how you are translating

Comment: Improved formatting and removed the last line as it was not related to the same problem. Also added the *translation* tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the contents of this file:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php

I think you need a different translation:

> {
>           "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Jeśli masz problem z kliknięciem \":actionText\" to skopiuj i wklej poniższy adres URL do przeglądarki internetowej: [:actionURL](:actionURL)" }

As for adding a logo, you can run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

and the `email.blade.php` file should be added to `resources/views/vendor/notifications`.

Comment: Thank you. How I can found this translation: This password reset link will expire in 60 minutes ? "This password reset link will expire in 60 minutes": "Ten link wygasa po 60 minutach", - this is not working :(

Comment: Change "60" to ":count". Relevant file here (line 63): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php

Comment: In general, if you're looking for a translation, you can go to Laravel's Github page and enter part of the text in the search bar, then select "In this repository".